# Return condition always is false into subscribe Angular CanActivate Guard

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, routes

I have this method inside a ward that captures the current path and compares it to the user's available paths.

But since the condition is inside the subscribe I have asynchrony problems since my Hasaccess variable always remains as false since the .subscribe is executed later when the function has already returned the value.

@Injectable()
export class UserAccessGuard implements CanActivate {

```
constructor(private router : Router,
    private commonSv : CommonSv) {}

canActivate() : boolean {

    const routesAllowed = this.commonSv.getRoutesAllowed(); //list of strings
    let hasAccess: boolean = false;

    this.router.events.subscribe(
        (event: any) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            let matchRoutes = routesAllowed.filter(route => route === this.router.url)
            hasAccess = (matchRoutes.length > 0)
        }
     });

      return hasAccess; //always false because subscribe is executed more last
    }
 }
```

How can I solve this? How can I make it return only within my .subscribe?

Comment: Does it help if I tell you that canActive can return an Observable<boolean>? You can return this.router.events (without subscribe) and use a pipe -> map to perform your checks.

Comment: Why are you checking for NavigationEnd? Isn't canActivate called before NavigationEnd?

Comment: Have you tried to return `this.router.events` directly? The `canActivate` method can return an observable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is return the observable containing true/false.

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean>...
```

and inside

```
return this.router.events.pipe(
    map((event: any) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            let matchRoutes = routesAllowed.filter(route => route === this.router.url)
            return (matchRoutes.length > 0)
        }
    })
)
```